# Android marketplace - public key

Tags: android, google-play

I'm just about to submit an application to the Android Marketplace.
There is this message when I try to upload the app:
Remember to change the public key in updates for this application to match your new public key on the Edit Profile page

Where can I find the public key?
I went to http://market.android.com/publish/Home and click on "edit profile" but I don't see any public key there.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

When using eclipse to do development, right click the project and select **Android Tools** Then select Export Signed Package (or something similar to that). It will walk you through creating your private key. Make sure you save the key because you will need to use the same key to update the application in the future on the market.